# nodejs facebook feeds with delay

Tags: node.js, facebook, graph, get, feed

i've written a batch in nodejs  to get the feeds from a particular facebook user-id; the nodejs (version 0.10.33) code uses node module fb version 0.7.0 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) .
the batch's request is scheduled every 5 minutes .

the facebook API response usually gives me back many feeds with a few minutes delay  between the request's time and the created_at/updated_at feed values  .

however sometimes i get some missing feeds that are visible in the user's page on the request's time.

after many requests and many hours i finally get those missing feeds but the strange thing is that their created_at/updated_at fields values are the same as their publishing time.

some idea ?

Comment: What endpoint of the Graph are you requesting? There can be differences between someones Facebook feed and the feed that is returned from the API. Also if you are making a whole heap of batch requests then you should expect it to be slower than making a small amount of requests.

Comment: the endpoint is : **GET /v2.1/{user-id}/feed** . just to explain better if i launch the batch now i can get back 2 of the 5 feeds of the user's facebook page that are posted at (we can call) **time1** ...after many hours if i launch again the batch  i get back the remaining 3 feeds and their created_at date field is always **time1** : it seems that facebook returns those feeds with a big delay..

Answer (score 0):

finally i found that the admin of a facebook page can decide to post his feeds in every date (past and future) he wants by the functions "RESCHEDULE" or "PROGRAMMED".

so, even if the feed is written now (call it **time1**), it appears on the user's page at the decided date (call it **time2**) ; the creation date on the page is **time1** and the facebook's api for this feed returns  created_at/updated_at=**time1** .

when at  **time2** i launch my batch i get back created_at/updated_at=**time1** for that feed : this is the final reason i often get a big delay between the feed's publishing date and the batch's request time.